# display data from sqlite to label using FMDB

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios5, ios6, fmdb

How to display data from SQLite to label using FMDB like this:

[image]

I would like to display whatever the output is in this format for the user to see. No Interaction. Only display for the `select` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add `UILabel` objects, just iterate through your result set, adding labels to your view. Something like:

```
NSInteger rowNum = 0;
NSArray *columnWidths = @[@(50), @(120), @(75), @(75)];
CGFloat rowHeight = 24.0;

FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:sql];

while ([rs next])
{
    CGFloat x = 0.0;
    NSInteger colNum = 0;
    for (NSNumber *columnWidth in columnWidths)
    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,
                                                                    rowHeight * rowNum, 
                                                                    [columnWidth floatValue], 
                                                                    rowHeight)];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        label.text = rs[colNum++];
        [self.view addSubview:label];
        x += [columnWidth floatValue];
    }
    rowNum++;
}

[rs close];
```

I just typed that in, so I'm sure there are typos in there, but hopefully it's enough to give you an idea of what it could look like. If there are too many rows to fit on a screen, you would add a scrollview to your view, and then add the labels as a subview to that.

I also think the tableview is a wonderful approach. Or dynamically built a HTML string that you show in a `UIWebView`. Tons of options here. It depends a little upon what your ultimate goal is here, the nature of the data, what sort of user interaction you want.

Comment: Thank You Sir. Since you are hardcoding the width of the cell ,if the text is longer than then cell width What should be done.ie: Is there anyway the column width can autosize itself based on the data inserted.Thanks again for looking into it.

Comment: @JacobWood Again, tons of options, but that's a bit of a hassle with programmatically added `UILabel` controls. Perhaps iterate once through your result set, calling `NSString` method [`sizeWithFont`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:) and programmatically determine the max widths of all of the columns in your `columnWidths` array. Alternatively, if you built HTML table, then column widths are taken care of for you.

Comment: There is no Interaction with the data, just a simple display in the format mentioned in the image above.

Comment: Thats Great idea Rob . I will implement the above code and test .Thanks again Sir for your time.Have a Great Day.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the above by using a *UITableView* and **custom** *UITableViewCells*.

And you can maintain an array which will act as a data source to your view controller.

Considering that you want to have the same layout as you have shared (which has four labels per row), you will be fetching the data from a database.

Since, the data fetched from a database may keep on increasing, UITableView is your best bet when displaying long list of data as memory management and cell creation is handled automatically.

If you plan to have only labels then things can get *tricky* for you. Because if the number of rows that you fetch using `select` query is too much then you will end up creating a lot of views which will cause memory issues.

And, if you don't want you user to interact with any of the rows, then implement the following method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Here is a link for creating custom cells:

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Here is a link for using table view:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/

Good Luck!!

Comment: I dont want to implement tableview only labels, is it possible? And can you please give me link to the suggestion you posted.Thanks Ravi.

Comment: Thanks Ravi.Can you please provide the link to the source code which satisfies the above requirement .It would be of a great help.Since I have no idea to how to proceed with the above requirement.Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope this helps. Do think about the memory issues if you're not going to implement a table view.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I guess Rob has the closest Answer.Thanks again and Have a Great day.