# error fmdb set label.text

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, fmdb

I am using the below code to create a table.I get this error `[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` at
 `label.text = rs[colNum++];`

How Do I fix it? Thanks in Advance.

```
NSInteger rowNum = 0;
NSArray *columnWidths = @[@(50), @(120), @(75), @(75)];
CGFloat rowHeight = 24.0;

FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:sql];

while ([rs next])
{
    CGFloat x = 0.0;
    NSInteger colNum = 0;
    for (NSNumber *columnWidth in columnWidths)
    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,
                                                                    rowHeight * rowNum, 
                                                                    [columnWidth floatValue], 
                                                                    rowHeight)];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        label.text = rs[colNum++];
        [self.view addSubview:label];
        x += [columnWidth floatValue];
    }
    rowNum++;
}

[rs close];
```

Comment: It contains key/value pairs basically the column name and the value for that column per row.

Comment: Then it's not an NSString. Uilabel's text property expects a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that some of your columns in your result set are not text values. As I recall from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132984/display-data-from-sqlite-to-label-using-fmdb/14133327#14133327) from which this stems, one of your columns is the `rowid`, you have some text columns, and then you have some numeric columns. So instead of:

```
label.text = rs[colNum++];
```

You should probably have something like:

```
id value = rs[colNum];
if ([[rs columnNameForIndex:colNum] isEqualToString:@"rowid"])
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [value intValue]];
else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    label.text = value;
else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

    label.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:value]];
}
else
    label.text = [value description];
colNum++;
```

Clearly, your logic will change depending upon whether you have a `rowid` column in your result set, or how many decimal places you want for floating point numbers, etc. It all depends upon what you put in the `sql` statement, but hopefully this gives you an idea of what you might do.

Comment: Thanks Rob.That was Awesome .Finally I can see the data.I would like to ask if I am taking each data separately like this :  **NSString *id = [rs stringForColumn:@"id"];
 
 NSString *data = [rs stringForColumn:@"data"];
 
 NSString *moreData = [rs stringForColumn:@"moreData"];

 label.text = id;
 colNum++;
 label.text = data;
   colNum++;
 label.text = moreData;
 
 [self.view addSubview:label];
 x += [columnWidth floatValue];**   BUt its repeating the data.I have more control over this .So how do I implement this way?

Comment: Perhaps we should move this into chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22239/chat-with-jacob-wood-re-fmdb-result-sets

Comment: Instead of doing the conversion like this, you could just do:  `[label setText:[rs stringForColumn:colNum++]];`

Comment: @DaveDeLong Perhaps, but then you can't control the format of number of decimal places for `price` field, or what have you.